# Where to get context for a new Intent when calling out of an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I think I am not getting something about the android activity lifecycle.

So here's my situation - I have an AsyncTask that does the job of uploading an XML file to a server. It is called when the user presses a button after filling out the required data in the activity. After it is called, I don't really need the activity anymore, so I call finish(); immediately.

```
task = new ASSend(data);
task.execute();
finish();
```

However, I need to display error messages in case something goes wrong during the execution of the AsyncTask (so I need to use either an AlertDialog or a dialog-themed intent), and I also need to open files in doInBackground with

```
FileInputStream fis;    
fis = context.openFileInput(filePath);
```

which requires a context. Is it possible to pass the context of the activity that started the AsyncTask to do all this, even though the activity that launched the AsyncTask no longer exists?

Comment: You can keep a reference to it but that would be the feared context leak: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: why dont you make a new dialog activity that the async task will start if upload fails. it can ask the user to try again also...

Comment: Launch service (instead of force AsyncTask start in you Activity) which executes your ASyncTask. You can do in background service everything you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `AsyncTask` is the correct class to use here. I think you should use an `IntentService` instead, for a few reasons:

1. `Service`s have a higher process priority, meaning processes that host active `Service`s are less likely to be killed by the system. In other words, using an `AsyncTask` inside an `Activity` would be more risky because the system would be more likely to kill your application process in low-memory situations.
2. You don't need to worry about leaking an activity context (since the `Service` isn't tied directly to the `Activity` lifecycle).
3. It's immediate--you don't need to block the user interface with a `Dialog` and wait for the task to complete. You can just queue up a task to be performed using an `IntentService` and leave the `Activity` immediately, and the task will eventually be executed asynchronously.

Comment: I'd add that your error reporting should probably be notifications instead of dialogs. The user may not even be using your app when the error dialog pops up. That's rude.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you shouldn't call `finish()` on the activity immediately. Try just adding a progress dialog in your async task to show a loading screen of sorts.

```
public class task extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>  {
ProgressDialog mDialog;
Context mContext;

    public task (Context context) {
         this.mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    mDialog.setMessage("Preparing Route...");
    mDialog.show();
}

    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object obj) {
    mDialog.dismiss();
            // then call finish?
}
```

Comment: This will be really janky though. Instead of immediately exiting the activity as desired, you need to pop up a dialog and wait for an indeterminate amount of time before being able to exit the activity.

Comment: I actually neet to allow the user to work in an another activity while the xml is being uploaded - it can get very big.

Comment: @AlcherBlack, if that is so, why not pass intent to another activity immediately after calling execute, rather than `finish();`

Comment: Use an `IntentService`.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, call this.getApplicationContext() to get a context that will live beyond the lifetime of the Activity.

Comment: but linus's answer is better.